# phpmyadmin CoreExtension.php#1608array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, twig

I have problem with twig. i installed phpmyadmin through apt and it depends on php-twig that seems old. currently the newest version of twig is `3.2.1` and for one in apt repo is `2.10.0-2` (i don't know if they are not compatible versions).

Anyway i saw this error on phpmyadmin:

`phpmyadmin in ./../../php/Twig/Extension/CoreExtension.php#1608array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated. Use isset() or property_exists() instead`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the twig would not be updated and i just tried to edit the file pointed in the error and that worked.

first i typed in bash: (i found the file with `find` command)

`sudo mousepad /usr/share/php/Twig/Extension/CoreExtension.php`

(in mousepad you can see line numbers by edit>preferences then check `show line numbers`).

and went to line `1608`(with CTRL+l), then replaced the line with the following line:

`if (isset($object->$item) || property_exists($object, (string) $item)) {`

That's all! phpmyadmin is working now without any error.

Comment: Compared to the array_key_exists() method, in property_exists() method, the variable $object is the second argument and the string variable, the first one. i didn't pay attention on that difference and I was still having some errors. But otherwise it works perfectly well. Thanks !

Comment: This links to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16746
And will be fixed in phpMyAdmin 5.1.2